# Android: Calendar add days including month and year

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have a problem. I am using this code to "increase" or "decrease" one day. "value" is `1 or -1`. I have tried `c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, value);` and `c.add(Calendar.DATE, value);` The problem is:
if `value = 1`, it `increases` **day** by **1** and month and year don't budge at all and remain same.

if `value = -1`, it `decreases` **day** by **1** and after `30 days` it decrease the `year`.

I have tried everything but could not understand the behavior. I need to increase or decrease the whole date like it happens in `MYSQ`L, not just date or month or year.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(mDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, value);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
String newDtString = sdf.format(resultdate);
```

Comment: my requirement is... for example: 12/12/2015. I have to show data for every date like if user presses > this button date will be 13/12/2015. If he presses again and again the date would become 31/12/2015. Now, if user presses > again the date should be 1/1/2016. How would I handle this?

Comment: no, that is the problem. I dont know why isn't it working. it gives 2015-12-1

Comment: ok I have found one answer may be it could work. let me try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + value);
```

<strike>You'd also have to handle end cases when it's first or last day of year</strike>

Java handles this for you. Example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

try {
    calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("31 December 2015"));
} catch (ParseException e̋̋) { }
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Prints:

```
31 December 2015
01 January 2016
```

Comment: Right. Let me try this and come back to you in a moment